# Delphi Print in MS-Word using Staples

Tags: delphi, printing, ms-word

I'm trying to print documents in MS-Word. Either by TWordApplication or OleVariant is ok with me. Our printer has the option to print.
We use a Xerox printer with staple cababilities.
When i do everything manually, it works fine of course.
When i do it from code, i can't seem to make it work.

Delphi itself has as far as i know, no connection to set up staples directly. Not from code, not from MS-Word.
I set up 2 types of print jobs on my printer (advanced settings). One for normal printing and one for printing with 1 staple.
For both settings i made an export. Then i tried to import the setting where i needed them.
Unfortunately, the printer driver does not seem to like what i'm doing. Every time i try to import the setting for the staples, the driver seems to delete the import from the registry and uses its default. After i try to overwrite the entry 'DevMode' in any way, the entry in the registry is deleted and the printer goes to default mode.

I tried to import a registry file, but that fails.
I tried to import the value from the registry file and write it with WriteBinaryData, but that deletes the DevMode entry.
I tried to copy the registry value from another registry value somewhere in the Registry that holds the information of profiles that i created. Nothing seems to happen when i try that though.

can anyone help me with this, as far as i know, i tried everything, but i can't seem to make it work. It could also be that i did something wrong with the WriteBinaryData and the ReadBinaryData. If someone could give me a working example for that, i would be very greatful.

I work with Delphi XE2.

TIA

Comment: I can't even tell what the question is. You want to code the printing? Or you want to code the defining of printer config settings?

Comment: @JanDoggen, you might want to read a bit before you post a comment like that. To me that is very offensive. Furthermore, my post states what i am asking. If i would post the code i used, it would be useless, because i know it won't work and will only put the answer you might post in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

The `DEVMODE` structure is used internally by the printer driver, it includes internal data (even **driver heap**) and must not be modified unless you have a detailed HOWTO sheet from the manufacturer. What you are trying to achieve requires a more hardware-close viewpoint than reaching your printer trough OLE, and - *poorly* - there are no guarantees that *it can even be done* if the manufacturer did not provide an API directly for this purpose. (And normally they don't.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a macro within Word which does what you want, then copy this macro into your program. Obviously, you will have to change the syntax a certain amount. Also, macros in Word (and Excel) use constants which are defined within those programs but not within Delphi, so you will have to discover what their values are, then use those values in your program.

Comment: In office 2003 that is not possible. When you access the printer driver options and use a macro to go there, after you close the dialog, in VBA, there is only 1 line of code. That line says... start printer dialog. Maybe Office 2013 does it that way, but i can only test that tomorrow when i am at work.

Comment: @user2786317: Record a macro when you run the 'setup printer' option. This is where you are probably setting the 'staples' option, and the macro should contain code for the settings. After running 'setup printer', run 'print'.

Comment: Tested it with Office 2013. Instead of getting 1 line of code, Office 2013 returns nothing. Should not be possible either, because Office 2013 does not have code that supports printing. That is done using the API of the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable staples using you printer driver config? If so, circumvent the problem by installing te printer twice on windows, one with and one without staples, and select te printer you want upon printing. Word has an property in the COM API for that. I used this method myself for selection different papertrays.

Comment: i can't do that unfortunately. We used to solve this problem doing what you suggest, but now we have only 1 queue available. I can not make another copy of that one. I can connect to the IP of the printer and make it a local printer, but not every PC that connects that way has the staple option in the printer dialog box. Some do, some don't.